# Matlab: How to blend or fuse two rgb images?

Tags: matlab

Based on the attached image, how can I get the output image without effected by the black color in the input image? If I'm using `imfuse(input, background, 'blend'),` it's going to blend the input color and background color. **I wonder if there is method or algorithm built for this purpose**.
(Note that, the background color is light purple and dark puple + black in input image)

```
                                     input, background, output image
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create two example images, similar to those shown by you. Note that this is just a simple way to create two not-so-boring images for testing.

```
bg = bsxfun(@times,permute([0.9, 0.8, 1.0], [1,3,2]), ones(100,100));
obj = bsxfun(@times,permute([0.3, 0.1, 0.4], [1,3,2]), triu(ones(100,100)));
```

[image: example images]

Now, by using `imfuse(bg, obj, 'blend')`, you apply an alpha blending, which is according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing)

> the process of combining an image with a background to create the appearance of partial or full transparency.

This appears *not* to be what you want. What you probably want is to take take all non-black parts of `obj` and place them over `bg` *without* any transparency effects. Do do that, we first have to find the black and non-black parts in `obj`. Secondly, we remove the background wherever we want our object to be. Finally, we can just add `obj` to it, as black = 0.

```
% Find and save all parts of obj which are not black
mask = sum(obj,3) > 0;

% Remove background from locations where the object will be placed, then add object
result = bsxfun(@times, bg, ~mask) + obj;
```

[image: result]

*Some more explanation:*

In the first line, we use `sum(obj,3)` to sum R, G, and B for each pixel. By comparing that pixel-wise to zero, we get a matrix `mask`, which contains a `0` for each pixel that is black in `obj`, and a `1` otherwise.

Then, with `bsxfun(@times, bg, ~mask)`, we multiply each channel R, G, and B of the background image `bg` by the inverse of the mask, i.e. by `1` if the pixel is black in `obj` (i.e. we want to use the background), and by `0` if we want to replace that pixel by the object. The result of this will be the background image, with zeros wherever `obj` is not zero, and with its original value wherever `obj` *is* zero. Thus, we can simply add `obj` to that and obtain our result.